# laravel website after registration gets stuck into controller sometimes

Tags: php, html, laravel

i have a laravel website, which has login and registration, after registration, the values are entered in database and sent to email,

the register controller is as below:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Register;
use App\Mail\SendEmail;
use Session;
use Mail;
use Storage;
use Auth;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

class RegController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        //
    }


    public function userfind(Request $request)
    {
        $user =   User::where('username',$request->user)->value('username');
        return  $user;
    }

    public function userfindemail(Request $request)
    {
        $user =   User::where('email',$request->email)->value('email');
        return  $user;
    }


    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {




        // return $request->Fee;
        $data = new Register;
        $data->firstname = $request->firstname;
        $data->lastname = $request->lastname;
        $data->mobilenumber = $request->mobilenumber;
        $data->experience = $request->experience;
        $data->designation = $request->designation;
        $data->confirmation = $request->confirmation;
        $data->company = $request->company;
        $data->address = $request->address;
        $data->addressline2 = $request->addressline2;
        $data->city = $request->city;
        $data->state = $request->state;
        $data->pin = $request->pin;
        $data->country = $request->country;
        $data->Whatsapp = $request->Whatsapp;
        $data->alternatenumber = $request->alternatenumber;
        $data->Email = $request->Email;
        $data->CompanyRegNumber = $request->CompanyRegNumber;
        $data->Date_Incorporation_orBusi_Stp = $request->Date_Incorporation_orBusi_Stp;
        $data->GSTIN = $request->GSTIN;
        $data->Services_Offered = $request->Services_Offered;
        $data->Annual_Turnover = $request->Annual_Turnover;
        $data->Declaration = $request->Declaration;
        $data->Fee = $request->Fee;


        $data->termsandconditions = $request->termsandconditions;
        // $data->Fee = $request->Fee;
        $data->Mode_of_Payment = $request->Mode_of_Payment;

        $data->Recommended_by_A = $request->Recommended_by_A;

        $data->Recommended_by_B = $request->Recommended_by_B;

        // user login
        $user = new User;
        $user->name = $request->firstname." ".$request->lastname;
        $user->email = $request->Email;
        $user->username = $request->username;
        $user->password =  bcrypt($request->password);
        $user->save();

        $data->user_id =  $user->id;



        if($request->hasFile('Photo')) {
            $image = $request->file('Photo');
            $filename = time().$image->getClientOriginalName();
            $destinationPath = public_path('uploads/Photo');

            Storage::disk('public')->put($filename,  File::get($image));
            $data->Photo=$filename;
        }
        if($request->hasFile('Receipt')) {
            $image = $request->file('Receipt');
            $filename = time().$image->getClientOriginalName();
            $destinationPath = public_path('uploads/Receipt');
            Storage::disk('public')->put($filename,  File::get($image));
            $data->Receipt=$filename;
        }
        if($request->hasFile('Signature')) {
            $image = $request->file('Signature');
            $filename = time().$image->getClientOriginalName();
            $destinationPath = public_path('uploads/Signature');
            Storage::disk('public')->put($filename,  File::get($image));
            $data->Signature=$filename;
        }

        $data->save();
        Session::flash('registered','reg');


        $name = $request->firstname." ".$request->lastname;
        $subject = "TEIA";
        $message =  $data->id;

        $photo = $data->Photo;
        $sign = $data->Signature;
        $recipt= $data->Receipt;
        $email = 'teiamembers@gmail.com';
        $smail= $request->Email;



        // ->cc(['name1@domain.com','name2@domain.com'])
        Mail::to($email)->cc([$smail])->send( new SendEmail($subject,$message , $photo ,$sign,$recipt));


        //
        // return redirect('demo')->with(['reg'=>$data]);

        return back();
    }


    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }


    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }


    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $data =  Register::find($id);
        $data->firstname = $request->firstname;
        $data->lastname = $request->lastname;
        $data->mobilenumber = $request->mobilenumber;
        $data->experience = $request->experience;
        $data->designation = $request->designation;
        $data->confirmation = $request->confirmation;
        $data->company = $request->company;
        $data->address = $request->address;
        $data->addressline2 = $request->addressline2;
        $data->city = $request->city;
        $data->state = $request->state;
        $data->pin = $request->pin;
        $data->country = $request->country;
        $data->Whatsapp = $request->Whatsapp;
        $data->alternatenumber = $request->alternatenumber;
        $data->Email = $request->Email;
        $data->CompanyRegNumber = $request->CompanyRegNumber;
        $data->Date_Incorporation_orBusi_Stp = $request->Date_Incorporation_orBusi_Stp;
        $data->GSTIN = $request->GSTIN;
        $data->Services_Offered = $request->Services_Offered;
        $data->Annual_Turnover = $request->Annual_Turnover;
        $data->Declaration = $request->Declaration;
        $data->Fee = $request->Fee;

        $data->termsandconditions = $request->termsandconditions;
        // $data->Fee = $request->Fee;
        $data->Mode_of_Payment = $request->Mode_of_Payment;

        $data->Recommended_by_A = $request->Recommended_by_A;

        $data->Recommended_by_B = $request->Recommended_by_B;

        // user login
        $user =  User::find(Auth::user()->id);
        $user->name = $request->firstname." ".$request->lastname;
        $user->email = $request->Email;
        $user->username = $request->username;

        $user->save();

        $data->user_id =  $user->id;



        if($request->hasFile('Photo')) {
            $image = $request->file('Photo');
            $filename = time().$image->getClientOriginalName();
            $destinationPath = public_path('uploads/Photo');

            Storage::disk('public')->put($filename,  File::get($image));
            $data->Photo=$filename;
        }
        if($request->hasFile('Receipt')) {
            $image = $request->file('Receipt');
            $filename = time().$image->getClientOriginalName();
            $destinationPath = public_path('uploads/Receipt');
            Storage::disk('public')->put($filename,  File::get($image));
            $data->Receipt=$filename;
        }
        if($request->hasFile('Signature')) {
            $image = $request->file('Signature');
            $filename = time().$image->getClientOriginalName();
            $destinationPath = public_path('uploads/Signature');
            Storage::disk('public')->put($filename,  File::get($image));
            $data->Signature=$filename;
        }

        $data->save();

        return back();
    }


    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

so the problem is, after successful registration, the same page should load showing success message, its happening sometimes, so sometimes after successful registration, the page is stuck in register controller and displays blank white page which is the controller itself, can anyone please help me with this. thanks in advance.

here is my website link https://teia.website/teia

Comment: You can try this : return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'success msg'); and check does mail functionality is working?

Comment: @RahulPawar hi mate, sorry, the full controller i have posted please check it

Comment: yes, mail is working fine

Comment: use return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['msg', 'The Message']); or return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'success msg');

Comment: @RahulPawar can i use return redirect('/');

Answer (score 0):

buddy,Use Exception handling for debugging purpose, like try and catch.
maybe that will help whats wrong with the code.
If that dosent help, then look into your controller method is there any printing variable, like dd($request->all()).

Comment: error is not there, registration is successful, but sometimes it displays register controller instead of home page

Comment: can i use this return redirect('/'); to properly redirct it to home page

Comment: i think you should use redirect()->route('formdata').